# Getting USB information using DriveInfo, and somehow output information

Tags: c#, arrays, string, usb

I'm trying to create a piece of software that can save a USB device's info, such as: Name, Total Space, Free Space, Format Type, etc. I've used DriveInfo[] but I can't work out how to save each INDIVIDUAL piece for different USB devices separately, so I know which USB device applies to what info. I'm trying to save each USB device and it's info to a text file. Here's what I have:

```
 DriveInfo[] loadedDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo ld in loadedDrives)
            {
                if (ld.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
                    if (ld.IsReady == true)
                    {             
                            deviceInfo.Add(ld.VolumeLabel + ": , " + ld.TotalSize + ": , " + ld.AvailableFreeSpace + ": , " + ld.DriveFormat);              
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (String st in deviceInfo)
            {

                string[] deviceSel;
              //  DriveInfo dInfo;
                deviceSel = st.Split(splitChar);


                if (itemSelected.Contains(deviceSel[0]))
                {

                    //Check That USB drive is the one thats selected
                    MessageBox.Show(deviceSel[0]);
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Is there an easier way than what I've done? Because the further I try and solve the problem, the more complex the code gets. Cheers

Comment: Where's the text file part you speak of?

Comment: You might want to look at creating an object type for your USB info and serializing a list of them to xml if your not dead set on text file.

Comment: What I have so far, is the name of the device gets parsed into another class, which uses StreamWriter to write a text file. My issue is that I can only manage to get the name of the device into a variable, rather than each piece of info

Comment: Ok but we can't see the bit of code you want help with.

Comment: My problem isn't the writing to the text, its getting the specific piece of information into some sort of variable, so I can then write to a text file. Sorry if that's not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you don't need to put into an array of string, keep them as `DriveInfo`:

```
DriveInfo[] loadedDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
List<DriveInfo> deviceInfo = new List<DriveInfo>();

foreach (DriveInfo ld in loadedDrives)
{
    if (ld.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
    {
        if (ld.IsReady == true)
        {             
                deviceInfo.Add(ld);              
        }
    }
}

foreach (DriveInfo st in deviceInfo)
{
     //can write whatever you want now
}
```

But that first loop can be done a lot easier with linq:

```
DriveInfo[] loadedDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
var deviceInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                   .Where(d=>d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && d.IsReady);
```